# Wait for sonar qube quality gate on Azure DevOps

Tags: sonarqube, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm creating a pipeline as code using a YAML file on **Azure DevOps**, but i have a 'little' stoper; i don't know how to break the build when quality gates fail, on jenkins that option is as easy as this:

```
stage("Quality Gate") {
        steps {
          timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') {
            waitForQualityGate abortPipeline: true
          }
     }
 }
```

But, how to do the same but on Azure DevOps using YAML?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the UI way of creating build pipeline to learn more Yaml commands

For an instance,

From the below UI, control options helps you to define the **condition to success or fail the build**

---

### Condition : Only when all previous taks have succeeded

[image]

The corresponding yaml for this would be

```
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet build'
```

---

### Condition : Even if a previous task has failed. unless the build was canceled

```
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet build'

  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

---

### Condition : Even if a previous task has failed. even if the build was canceled

```
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet build'

  condition: always()
```

Like this you can find all the yaml commands (or) Syntax using the UI way of building pipeline

You can able to convert the UI -> Yaml by using below way

[image]

Comment: Hi, before that all thank you for your answer.

Im doing it in sometimes; I add the task on "UI designer", and after I look at the autogenerated YAML. But exactly, what official plugin  could I use to break my pipelines if quality gates fails?

Comment: you just need the install the [sonarqubue extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarqube) where you can use the publish quality gate task from which you can able to control the needed configurations

Answer (score 1):

Hello developers and devops

I have created a little BashScript to break the builds when sonar quality gates fail, this work with any language and any build tool and any CI server
https://github.com/carlosdeveloper10/wait-for-sonar-qg